# Devolver el elemento n de una lista Haskell

Tags: lista, haskell, programación-funcional

Cuando la lista no está vacía devuelve -4, sin importar cual sea n, hice una prueba de escritorio y parece funcionar pero no.

```
nElem :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
nElem [] n = -1
nElem (x:xs) n | n == 0 = x
               | n /= 0 = nElem xs n-1
```

Edito:

Casos: nElem [1,2,3] 2, devuelve -4;
nElem [1,2] 1, devuelve -3

Y esta es la prueba de escritorio que hice en papel aplicando la definición, pero debe estar mal algo capaz:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Devuelve -4 si la lista tiene tres elementos, supongo. ¿Puedes completar la pregunta con un caso de prueba?

Comment: @ChemaCortes Si, ahora la edito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En haskell la llamada a funciones tiene mayor prioridad que cualquier operación aritmética. Cuando pones `nElem xs n-1`, se ejecuta primero `nElem xs n` y luego hace la resta (Equivalente a `(nElem xs n)-1`). Así pues, si con la lista vacía retorna `-1`, entonces se va restando tantas unidades como elementos tienes. Si la lista es de tres elemento, devuelve -4. Si tiene dos elemento, devuelve -3. Sin importar el valor que tenga `n`.

Basta poner unos paréntesis:

```hs
nElem :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
nElem [] n = -1
nElem (x:xs) n | n == 0 = x
               | n /= 0 = nElem xs (n-1)
```

En los chequeos del final, basta con poner solo uno:

```hs
nElem :: [Int] -> Int -> Int
nElem [] n = -1
nElem (x:xs) n | n == 0 = x
               | otherwise = nElem xs (n-1)
```

Otra sugerencia: cuando devuelve `-1` nunca estarás seguro si ese era el elemento buscado o si no ha encontrado nada (eg: `nElem [2,-1,0] 1`). Lo que se suele hacer es que devuelva un tipo `Maybe`.

El código mejorado quedaría así:

```hs
nElem :: [Int] -> Int -> Maybe Int
nElem [] _ = Nothing
nElem (x:xs) n | n < 0 = Nothing
               | n == 0 = Just x
               | otherwise = nElem xs (n-1)
```